# Rails test throws failures with no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, shoulda

I am trying to understand better TDD. So I use `shoulda` in my rails app as so,

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProjectTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  should validate_presence_of(:description).with_message(/can.t be blank/)
end
```

And I get this message when running the test.

```
1) Failure:
ProjectTest#test: Project should require description to be set.  [/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/shoulda-context-1.1.6/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:344]:
Expected errors to include /can.t be blank/ when description is set to nil, got no errors

1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

here's my model

```
with_options unless: :privatize do  |project|
    project.validates :title, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}
    project.validates :description, presence: true
    ....
  end
```

What does this failure means ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: It means that the validation for the description attribute in the Project model is not implemented correctly. Specifically, it is not causing an error when `description` is not set (i.e. it is nil).

Comment: @Slicedpan thanks, so I updated my post, and I don't see where the error can come from

Comment: doesn't the `unless` option mean those validations will only be performed when the method `privatize` returns false? can you check what that method returns?

Comment: @Slicedpan OK you're right, I have this `def privatize
     self.private == true
  end` and by default, the `private` is set to `true`. How can I set this attribute to be `false` ?

Comment: I haven't used `shoulda` so i'm not sure how to do that. Can you create a specific instance of a Project to test with, then set its private attribute to false?

Comment: @Slicedpan that's precisely the question I am wondering about ;)

Comment: The best way to debug this is implement a test that checks that validation: initialize (`project = Project.new`), validate (`project.valid?`) and then inspect the object (`puts project.inspect`). you should see the errors and flags when you inspect it